# Launching pgAdmin v4 on a browser that is not the default one

Tags: browser, pgadmin, pgadmin-4

I have pgAdmin v4 installed, my default browser is Firefox, but I would like to open pgAdmin as a standalone app on Chrome. I fixed that problem following the procedure described in various Stackoverflow answers such as [Launch pgAdmin 4 as a standalone app using chrome browser commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52904897/launch-pgadmin-4-as-a-standalone-app-using-chrome-browser-commands) and [pgAdmin 4 v3.1 How can I use another browser? (Win 7)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51637530/pgadmin-4-v3-1-how-can-i-use-another-browser-win-7/51719736?noredirect=1#comment112501365_51719736), i.e. configuring the "Browser command" option of pgAdmin to use Chrome.

That worked till sometime ago, but with the latest versions (at least 4.24 an 4.25) there is a problem: when I launch pgAdmin it still opens the default browser and not Chrome, as I configured. However, if I right click on the icon of the system tray and select "New pgAdmin 4 window..." it correctly opens Chrome.

I thought it was just me, but I found that there is at least another user with the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by a developer of EnterpriseDB (the company behind pgAdmin) in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51637530/pgadmin-4-v3-1-how-can-i-use-another-browser-win-7/51719736?noredirect=1#comment112533716_51719736), that is a bug in the QT library that happens on Windows platform; it has already been reported and developers are working on that.